# Show a select emoji screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am doing a game with Unity3D in which there are 2 players using the same mobile device in turns to play.
I am adding a Settings scene in which each players enters his/her name and can select an Emojicon to use as an avatar in  the game.
I have already imported the png file in to my Resources folder and cut it to 80 sprites using the sprite editor called emojicons1_0 to emojicons1_79.
What I need is to enable the players to change the default emojicon in the Settings if they touch the existing emojicon or a button "Change" beside it. 
I was thinking of showing a scroll list from the asset called Gamestrap UI and display an array of 4 x 20 emojicons, and they can select there the desired emojicon. I don't know how to do this, and I appreciate any help. I am open to other suggestions of course.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using uGui, there is a number of ways to do it. I would simply create a view prefab, which will composed of scroll list with grid layout inside. It will have a script attach, which will initialise the view by loading textures/sprites and set it to image component of an instantiated button prefab, which represents one icon to select. Then view has callback and on click simply call it with selected image.

Here is references:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-scroll-rect

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GridLayoutGroup.html